# Best practice when pushing change sets through Dev->Test->Release sandboxes

Tags: change-set, bestpractice

Using Changesets to migrate changes in an org with Dev sandboxes and a UAT/Test sandbox:

I've always considered it good practice to push the changes from Dev->UAT for testing and then push the same changeset from Dev->Prod.

An alternative would be to push the change from Dev->UAT and then create a new changeset in UAT and push that from UAT->Prod.

However, I can't find any documentation, best practice information that states that the first approach is the better practice. It seems obvious to me, but when someone challenges me on that it would be nice to be able to reference material that confirms it.

So, is the first approach better than the second? and is there any material I can reference to confirm that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is no best practice here. It depends on how similar your environments are and what is your bug patching strategy.

Let's imagine you deployed a changeset from DEV to UAT and you discovered a bug.

Now to fix this you made some changes in the UAT directly because salesforce lets you do that and let's assume the fix is so small like giving a FLS for a field for an object for a permission set.

Now because of a business emergency, you did in UAT directly and then you recreated a changeset to push to PROD.

The above approach is ok but not optimal due to two obvious reasons

- A lot of work to recreate the change assuming the changeset is pretty big.
- Fixing in UAT might keep environments out of sync and you have to sync the changes back to dev.

In a clean strategy the optimal approach is to move from DEV -> UAT -> PROD.

It's generally recommended that you automate this using CI/CD tools using Salesforce CLI so you don't have to create these changesets and spend a lot of manual time having to track what you have changed.